# Scale procedural triangular pattern evenly

Tags: node-editor, scale, procedural

I want to make a triangular pattern scale evenly from left to middle - and from middle to right back.
I'm getting the issue that the shape is getting rounded toward the middle, and I'm not exactly sure how I can have the pattern not mirror.

The third image is sort of what I'm going for, minus the gaps in between.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quick thought, is it caused by the perspective from your camera/viewport?

Comment: a blend file would help to help you!

Comment: Hey I have uploaded a blend file! (made in 2.91.2) @jspr The camera is looking straight at the plane with the material. 
https://www.vincentvc.com/share/triangular-pattern.blend
As a reference, what I'm trying to achieve: https://www.artsy.net/artwork/bridget-riley-straight-curve